# unix: how to concatenate files matched in grep

Tags: unix, grep, cat

I want to concatenate the files whose name does not include "_BASE_". I thought it would be somewhere along the lines of ...

```
ls | grep -v _BASE_ | cat > all.txt
```

the cat part is what I am not getting right. Can anybody give me some idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
ls | grep -v _BASE_ | xargs cat > all.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore some files with `ls` using `--ignore` option and then cat them into a file.

```
ls --ignore="*_BASE_*" | xargs cat > all.txt
```

Also you can do that without `xargs`:

```
cat $( ls --ignore="*_BASE_*" ) > all.txt
```

**UPD**:
Dale Hagglund noticed, that filename like "Some File" will appear as two filenames, "Some" and "File". To avoid that you can use `--quoting-style=WORD` option, when `WORD` can be `shell` or `escape`.

For example, if `--quoting-style=shell` Some File will print as 'Some File' and will be interpreted as one file.

Another problem is output file could the same of one of `ls`ed files. We need to ignore it too.

So answer is:

```
outputFile=a.txt; ls --ignore="*sh*" --ignore="${outputFile}" --quoting-style=shell | xargs cat > ${outputFile}
```

Comment: Neither of these work if any of the filenames contains whitespace.  A filename like "Some File" will appear as two filenames, "Some" and "File", when passed to `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get also files from subdirectories, `find' is your friend:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*_BASE_*' ! -path ./all.txt -exec cat {} >> all.txt \+
```

It searches files in the current directory and its subdirectories, it finds only files (`-type f`), ignores files matching to wildcard pattern `*_BASE_*`, ignores `all.txt`, and executes `cat` in the same manner as `xargs` would.

Comment: +1 To limit to the current directory, add -maxdepth 1. This one should also cleanly handle files spaces in their name.

Comment: I'd quote the '*_BASE_*' part (doesn't work in zsh otherwise). Also prepend rm all.txt and do the redirection from cat with >>. The + at the end should probably be a ;

Comment: \+ is a deliberate choice to reduce the number of cats.

Comment: Didn't know about that modifier. Cool!