# * but excluding certain files

Tags: bash

I'd like to do something like

```
cat *
```

but which would ignore files that match the pattern `__*__`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable `extglob` in bash (`shopt -s extglob`), you can use

```
cat !(excluded_file|excluded_*_pattern)
```

`extglob` patterns:

```
| 
    or/alternatives
?(pattern-list)
    Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
*(pattern-list)
    Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
+(pattern-list)
    Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
@(pattern-list)
    Matches one of the given patterns
!(pattern-list)
    Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Comment: I'm running under Darwin—your `extglob` enabling code gives `-bash: shopt: extglob: invalid option name`

Comment: Sorry, I had `-o` originally (mixed it up with `set -o`), did you try it with the corrected `-s`?

Answer (score 2):

From [my today's answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531505/570689)

```
ls --ignore="__*__" --quoting-style=shell | xargs cat
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Darwin's implementation of `ls` does not include `--ignore` or `--quoting-style`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the *best* way, but:

```
tcsh -c 'echo ^__*__'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls
__a__  __b__  c

$ cat *
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccc

$ cat [!_]
ccccccccccccccc
```